# How do filter a pandas dataframe by other rows in the same dataframe?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Two pandas questions:

1. How do you join on a modified column without adding that column into a dataframe?
2. How do you do the equivalent of "left join ZZ on... where ZZ.ID is null"

I have an example below that has both of these features, in SQL.

Let's say I flip a coin 100 times, taking note of which flip it is. Each time it lands on HEADS, I add a row to a tabled called "coin_flips" with the "flipNumber."
The table looks like this

```
flipNumber
4
5
7
12
13
14
16
```

I want to pull each "flipNumber" that came prior to a gap in the count. From the example above, I want to pull 5,7,14, 16. With SQL, I could pull it like this:

```
select
   v1.flipNumber
from
 coin_flips v1
left join
 coin_flips v2
 on v2.flipNumber = v1.flipNumber +1
where
 v2.flipNumber is null
```

How do I do the same in pandas?

One solution I've found is to use **pandasql** which allows you to write sql queries against dataframes, but I'd like to know how to do it natively.

Comment: You do know you can [read_sql()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) in pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Setup

```
s = pd.Series([4, 5, 7, 12, 13, 14, 16], name='flipNumber')
```

#### Solution

```
s[(s.shift(-1) - s) > 1]
```

#### Explanation

get the difference from one number to the next with

```
s.shift(-1) - s
```

check if its greater than 1.  This identifies a gap

```
(s.shift(-1) - s) > 1
```

Use this as a mask on the original series

```
s[(s.shift(-1) - s) > 1]
```

---

This was able to get at what you said you were really after which was the first number prior to a gap.  Using your example, we should end up with `[5, 7, 14]`.  16 is not and should not be included as you don't know if there will be a subsequent gap.  If you insist the last point be included, we can modify it to be included but you'll have to specify a rule to do it.

pandas has joins, merges, concats, and more, but these weren't necessary to accomplish this task.

In the code I provided, the `(s.shift(-1) - s) > 1` does the opposite thing as you sql code `on v2.flipNumber = v1.flipNumber +1`

Comment: Out of curiosity, is `Series.shift(.)` a generator? I'm mostly thinking about the space complexity of the solution, does this solution add an O(n) to the complexity of not?